# create a global OnClickListener Android

Tags: android

Hi im wanting to create an onClickListener() in a Global.java class and then pass it variables this is so i can reuse the on click listener for different lists within fragments. heres what i have tried so far but I'm getting a few errors.

```
public static OnClickListener onClickListener(Context activityContext, View myView, ArrayAdapter<?> myadapter, int position ){

             OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener();

             @Override
             public static void onClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long arg3) 
             {
                   String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos); 
                   // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
                   // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
             }

             return onClickListener;

         }
```

then in my activity i do this

```
listView.setOnClickListener(Global.onClickListener(this, v, myAdapter, position));
```

These are the errors i'm getting in the Global.java

```
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   
void is an invalid type for the variable onClick
Cannot instantiate the type DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an interface

```
public interface MyOnItemSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(TextView t);
}
```

and have your parent activity implement it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyOnItemSelectedListener {

    ....

}
```

then, in your `ListView` fragment you create a variable that has this type

```
private MyOnItemSelectedListener listener;
```

and in the fragment's `onAttach` method you check that the activity does in fact implement the interface and then initialize it

```
if(activity instanceof MyOnItemSelectedListener ) {
    listener = (MyOnItemSelectedListener ) activity;
} else {
    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + 
        " must implement MyOnItemSelectedListener ");
}
```

Now, all you need to do is set the click listener of your `ListView` and call the method defined in the interface on your listener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView selected = (TextView) view;
        listener.onItemSelected(selected);
    }

});
```

Lastly, you implement the `onItemSelected` method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(TextView t) {
    String content = t.getText().toString();
}
```

And you're done.